# What are the finite subgroups of $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry

I've read the following question:

[Finite subgroups of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (reference request)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27258/finite-subgroups-of-rm-sl-2-mathbbz-reference-request)

and it made me wonder. It's easy to see that $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})=\operatorname{Sp}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. So does it remain true that $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{Z})$ has only finitely many finite subgroups, if $n$ is general? If not, can we still say something about the possible orders of its finite subgroups? (For example, must they be divisible by only finitely many primes?)

Comment: Yes, there's a bound on the order that depends on $n$. The idea is to show that most congruence subgroups are torsion-free.

Comment: For any Chevalley group $G$ (e.g., ${\rm{Sp}}_{2n}$) there is a systematic approach to getting a uniform upper bound (in terms of the root system) on the size of finite subgroups, even working inside $G(k)$ for a fixed number field $k$.  See Theorem 5 in section 5.4 of part II of https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-pierre-serre/UPL3821667391778701726_6___Bounds_for_the_orders.pdf (where $t=\ell-1$ for $\ell$ unramified in $k$). The conjugacy aspects seem to be much more subtle (especially if you only work with $\mathbf{Z}$-points); see Theorem 8 in section 6.6 of part II for a sample.

Comment: The bound through congruence subgroups being torsion-free amounts to using a bound from ${\rm{GL}}_{2n}$. The methods in Serre's paper give better bounds because they uses more refined information about the structure of the chosen algebraic group (and the bounds are even shown to be optimal in many cases when restricted to $\ell$-groups for prime $\ell$).

Comment: It has infinitely many finite subgroups. Probably you have another question in mind, namely: does it have finitely isomorphism type of subgroups (yes, because it's virtually torsion-free, and you have bounds on the possible orders using the embedding into $\mathrm{SL}_{2n}(\mathbb{Z})$), or, more interesting, does it have finitely many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups. The latter is still true, but less obviously and I'm not sure of a reference (and unlike the previous question, it does not boil down to $\mathrm{SL}_{2n}(\mathbb{Z})$).

Comment: As mentioned in MO106338, Zassenhaus proved the finiteness result ( following results of Blichfeldt,Schur, Jordan etc), and there is a proof in the 1962 edition of Curtis and Reiner.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: just to make your statement more precise: the link is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106338/, and it refers to the finiteness of the number of conjugacy classes of finite subgroups in $\mathrm{GL}_m(\mathbb{Z})$. But this does not imply that all its subgroups also have finitely many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups; it's probably false in general, while it's certainly true for $\mathrm{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Anyway, the question does not seem to be about the conjugacy classification.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be done by Markus Kirschner (see [these 2011 talk notes)](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~grgr/kirschmer.pdf).

Comment: The problem (of the classification, not just the finiteness result) is indeed tackled these slides. It provides some kind of procedure; he obtains classification of *maximal* finite subgroups up to dimension $2n=22$.